# Disabling keyboard/mouse in Java

Tags: java

I am working on a program, which allows the user to lock the computer, so no one else can use it. Is there anyway, I can disable the mouse, and specific keys on the keyboard? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No but you can create have your program locking the screen and then using a MouseMovementListener so each time the mouse moves, you return it programatically to some point in the screen ( it would look like it doesn't move anymore )

Comment: Can I do the same with keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

over Linux you can use xinput enable id
you can get the id throw xinput without parameters.

```
Process p;

 p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("xinput disable 12");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a portable way and I'm pretty sure Java does not supply anything like that in fact. However on Windows this can be done with [BlockInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But if you were going to code JNI/JNA you might as well use [LockWorkStation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it if you are implementing the [MouseListener interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html). In the MouseClicked method you could check a boolean before actually performing any action. When you want to disable or enable the action change the state of that boolean.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to lock the screen then you can use java [Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class. And if you want to block the keyboard and mouse events when Windows is locked then there is no need. Since locking the screen results in disabling all the inputs.