# Is there way to block mouse & keyboard in Java

Tags: java, input, mouse, disable

In my program I'm having a thread that is doing stuff with java Robot. This thread includes delays so I would like to prevent myself interrupting the robot by moving mouse or clicking. So is there a way to mouse input in Java?

Comment: You can check the MouseListener class - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - Freeze Mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724973/java-freeze-mouse)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling keyboard/mouse in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351307/disabling-keyboard-mouse-in-java)

Comment: try to consume any mouse event or keyboard event