# Is there a way to disable all desktop access using a Java-based Application?

Tags: java, swing

So, I'm trying to make a Health App that forces you to not use your computer during the night. I want to make it in Java and its purpose is to block all access to the computer while it's running. What that means is, the app will be fullscreen and will show "This computer is locked until SomeHour AM".

I want the app to block any user input (keyboard or mouse), so no closing the app. Can I do that with Java? If so, what is the best way possible? (I'm making the GUI in Swing).

If I can't, is it possible to do it with another programming language?

Comment: "Health App", ransomware. Po-tay-to, po-tah-to

Comment: Most likely not possible with Java, at least unless you use JNI to use some native libraries that give you that level of control over the machine. And note: worst case, people could still just pull the power plug

Comment: You will have to lock the PC at the operating system level. An OS which would allow you to do this is not a good OS.

Comment: It's not for anything like that. It's for a programming marathon.

Comment: @GhostCat I'll make it run at startup

Comment: @rajeev Windows can boot into safe mode which will skip that, then the user can uninstall it and restart.

Comment: @Michael I was thinking of something like a keyboard/mouse driver disabler or like a keylogger that doesn't let you alt+f4 (this is very possible to make)

Comment: **If** you can do it, then you'll need to use some native APIs to do it, meaning Java won't be much help. In fact it'll probably make the job harder than easier.

Comment: @Michael I mean, it's a health app. If the user can do all of this, then surely they just don't want to sleep better. I'm not trying to make the app block all computer access, I just want to stop the user from accessing everything for the period of time that they set. If they really need to access it, they would need a fail-safe.

Comment: Yeah, most people these days, when they spend too much time in front of electronic devices, then we are talking devices. I think the amount of people willing to use/pay for an app that locks their windows PC is ... rather limited.

Comment: Btw, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351307/disabling-keyboard-mouse-in-java

Comment: And note: when your app goes wrong for some reason, it has a lot of potential to really really annoy your users.

Comment: @GhostCat it's desktop to start, for people like me who barely sleep... Then I can make it for mobile devices as well...

I'll make a fail-safe, no problem about that.

If I make the app fullscreen (with no decorations) and then make a keylogger that presses something else whenever the user tries to press something, and also tries to block the mouse using some listener, would that work?

Comment: Honestly, I dont know. You see, standard java absolutely won't do. You wont get java to see things like "alt f4", or "alt tab" to go to your app FIRST, before the OS kicks in. So you need native stuff. Which makes everything more complicated.

Comment: @rajeev: I'm absolutely positive that no "normal" application can intercept key-combinations like Ctrl-Alt-Delete or even Ctrl-Shift-Escape without burrowing deeply into the system. Even **if** this can be achieved, Java is probably the worst tool for the job. Read up on [Secure attention key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_attention_key).

Comment: I agree with Joachim. You have to understand that the OS is ALWAYS the first instance that captures keys, no matter what you told your application to do. The OS decides what to do about those keystrokes. And as Joachim says. without a deep dive into native Windows APIs you will not be able to suppress "alt tab" being  consumed and acted on by the OS. Maybe your app should simply just put up a screen and tell people: "put your laptop to sleep, and then put yourself to sleep". You are spending a ton of energy into something that promises very few return on investment.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because even if this task is possible in some language, it's not Java. Java aims to be useful across platforms, rather than delving into the intricacies of each OS.